# Password from return url of recuring paypal payment is not matched with the one in the paypal confirmation page

Tags: paypal-subscriptions, recurring

i have integrated the recurring paypal payment method in mysite. In this method , i get the username and password from the return url. The username is same on both the return url and paypal confirmation page. **But the password is different in both return url and paypal confirmation page.** 
i need the same password in both confirmation page and return url.
My code is . .

```
<form action="paypal.php" method="post">  
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->  
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="alice@mystore.com">  
 <!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->  
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">  
 <!-- Identify the subscription. -->  
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alice's Weekly Digest">  
 <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="DIG Weekly">  
 <!-- Set the terms of the 1st trial period. -->  
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
 <input type="hidden" name="a1" value="0">  
 <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="14">  
 <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="D">  
 <!-- Set the terms of the 2nd trial period. -->  
 <input type="hidden" name="a2" value="5.00">  
 <input type="hidden" name="p2" value="3">  
 <input type="hidden" name="t2" value="W">  
 <!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->  
 <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="49.99">  
 <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">  
 <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">  
 <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">  
  <input type="hidden" name="usr_manage" value="1">  

  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://server/projects/ananth/subscribebutton/thanks.php">  

 <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"  
 src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif"  
 alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">  
 <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"  

src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >  
</form>
```

In this paypal confirmation page, the username and password are as follows

**Password: deal2minor
Username: pp-cheersidle**

In this Return url page, the username and password are as follows

**Password :  ojjxcsIatFLp2
Username :  pp-cheersidle**

I need the same password in the confirmation page to get returned in the return url. So only i can store it in my database .

Please advise me. . .  .